# Muon pair production

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Does muon pair production ($e^+ + e^- \rightarrow \mu^+ + \mu^-$) not have a $t$-channel at the lowest order (at the tree level)? All sources like Schwartz, etc. seem to only solve for $s$-channel, which I can see. But I think there is a $t$-channel as well. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

You can answer this question by drawing the diagrams for the Mandelstam variables. Below, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables), with time increasing to the right:

[image: Mandelstam variables]

In the s-channel, the intermediate trajectory is timelike, so the two electrons disappear at the earlier vertex, while the two muons appear at the later vertex.  In the t- and u- channels, the intermediate state is spacelike, and $\rm ee\to \mu\mu$ would require a flavor-changing interaction at each vertex.

Comment: I see flavor is conserved in electromagnetism, maybe I will learn more about this in electroweak theory. Thank you! :)